# Append API json response to MetaInfo Vue js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-meta

i have a meta tag that have structure like this

```
  metaInfo () {
    return {
      title: 'my title',
      meta: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'my description'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:title',
          content: 'my title2'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:site-name',
          content: 'my site name'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:type',
          content: 'website'
        },
        {
          name: 'robots',
          content: 'index,follow'
        }
      ]
    }

  },
```

and i want to append my api response to my meta tag, but i don't know how to make a data  like this

this is my API response

```
data: [{meta_tags_id: 3, meta_tags_properties: "my property", meta_tags_content: "my content"}]
0: {meta_tags_id: 3, meta_tags_properties: "my property", meta_tags_content: "my content"}
meta_tags_content: "my content"
meta_tags_id: 3
meta_tags_properties: "my property"
error: 0
message: "successfully get all meta tags"
```

this is the expected result
{
property: my property,
content: my content
}
and how do i append my json response to my metaInfo?

Comment: add the API response data also and would be great if you can show what is your desired result

Comment: done sir @decpk

Comment: Add api response as a text not as a picture and desired result as an object. It is not so clear what exactly do you want to do.

Comment: done sir, sorry @decpk

Comment: Answered, Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `metaInfo` is a function that returns an `object`, So collect that object in a container i.e `metaInfoData`.

map over your `data` array and convert it into required format and then append it into `metaInfoData.meta`

```js
const metaInfo = function () {
  return {
    title: "my title",
    meta: [
      {
        name: "description",
        content: "my description",
      },
      {
        property: "og:title",
        content: "my title2",
      },
      {
        property: "og:site-name",
        content: "my site name",
      },
      {
        property: "og:type",
        content: "website",
      },
      {
        name: "robots",
        content: "index,follow",
      },
    ],
  };
};

const data = [
  {
    meta_tags_id: 3,
    meta_tags_properties: "my property",
    meta_tags_content: "my content",
  },
];

const metaInfoData = metaInfo();
const convertedData = data.map((obj) => {
  const { meta_tags_properties, meta_tags_content } = obj;
  return {
    property: meta_tags_properties,
    content: meta_tags_content,
  };
});
metaInfoData.meta = [...metaInfoData.meta, ...convertedData];
console.log(metaInfoData);
```

Comment: can you tell me how do i map those data to an array and convert it? sorry sir im tottaly new in javascript

Comment: user inbuilt map function in js`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: See my code where I've used `data.map((obj) => {.......`

Comment: sir @decpk but how do i convert my response.data.data to const data =[] ?

Comment: `const data = [...response.data.data]` simple

Comment: what is '...' means?

Comment: Array destructuring Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231471/discussion-between-decpk-and-someone-that-needhelp).

Comment: my metaInfo() is some kind like mounted(), created () method that need to called on script and its not a cuntion, i need to somehow append my response.dat.data (can be mor than 1 data) to meta : [converted meta object